# Rewrite getProductUrl in product_viewed.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9

How to rewrite `getProductUrl()` in `template/reports/product_viewed.phtml` ?

I tried using `config.xml`:

```
    <blocks>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product_abstract>Vela_Product_Block_Product_Abstract</product_abstract>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
```

And

```
<?php
class Vela_Product_Block_Product_Abstract extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
    public function getProductUrl($product, $additional = array())
    {
        return "weleeeh";
    }
}
```

but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot override some classes in Magento. `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` is one of them.
Actually you can, but it has no effect because the class you are rewriting is never instantiated.
Only it's child classes are instantiated.
And even if you rewrite the class, the child classes still extend the original class.
The only solution in this case is the ugly way of doing it, by copying the class in the `local` codepool and doing your modifications there.
Or, your can rewrite onlt the child class of the main class that you need.
From what I understand you need to rewrite the getProductUrl method on the `Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed` block.
for that replace your config xml part from your question with:

```
<blocks>
    <reports>
        <rewrite>
            <product_viewed>Vela_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed</product_viewed>
        </rewrite>
    </reports>
</blocks>
```

then create the file `app/code/local/Vela/Reports/Block/Product/Viewed.php` with this content

```
<?php
class Vela_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed extends Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed
{
    public function getProductUrl($product, $additional = array())
    {
        return "weleeeh";
    }
}
```